# Pdf to image conversion takes an enormous amount of space

Tags: python, image, pdf, memory

I have a quick and dirty python script that takes a pdf as input and saves the pages as an array of images (using [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image)).

What I don't understand: 72 images take up 920MB of memory. However, if I save the images to file and then reload them, I get to barely over 30-40MB (combined size of the images is 29MB). Does that make sense?

I also tried to dump the array using pickle and I get to about 3GB before it crashes due to MemError. I'm at a complete loss what is eating up so much memory...

Comment: The tool most likely stores meta-data in memory while it's decoding. Such as uncompressed color mappings (remember, PNG and JPG is compressed, but the raw data will take up quite a lot more space). So depending on how large the images are and what ammount of colors etc they have, yes. Sounds resonate. The pickle module (without know exactly the inner workings) most likely copies all your values, has to pack them into a structure that it's familiar with which easily doubles the memory usage. Sadly, the only way to work there is chunk it up.

Comment: That was my suspicion. How can I free up the metadata? Somehow there has to be a way to clean it up manually (garbage collection module doesn’t work)

Comment: You'd have to submit a bug report, feature request or create a patch that fixes the problem for this library. My best guess is that you can't at the moment. I've used the library before, but never had issues with it because I've never really worked on large PDF's with many/large images.

Comment: OK I found the culprit: the module converts pdfs to ppm images which are absurdly huge. I have to find a way to convert the PPM to something like png or jpg and that should do the trick...

Comment: Have you tried `fmt=jpg` as a parameter?

Comment: Edit: it works! Just incredibly slow but changing the format works. @Torxed if you post this as an answer I can accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Glad it works! I think pdg2image uses PIL as it's underlaying library, make sure you keep that up to date and if you're running it in a VM, make sure you give the VM enough CPU resources to do the job quickly :) added a answer below, best of luck with the project! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the huge memory usage is most likely because of excessive ammount of meta data usage, uncompressed image data (raw color data) or a lossless image codec within the library/tool itself.

It might also depend on the size, amount of images etc.

On the last remark, regarding pickle. Pickle in itself is a memory dump format used by Python to preserve certain variable states. Dumping memory to a session state on disk is quite a heavy task. Not only do Python need to convert everything to a format that enables the saved state, but it must also copy all the data to a known state upon saving it. There for it might use up quite a lot of ram and disk in order to do so. (Only way around this it to chunk up the data usually).

Upon answering some comments, one solution would be to pass the parameter `fmt=jpg` which keeps the image in a compressed state lowering the resource usage a bit.